# WinRT create animated GIF

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-runtime

I'm working on creating some animated GIFs in a WinRT app.  I've got gif conversion working with multiple frames in the resulting image, but I cannot figure out how to set things like frame delay and repeat behavior.

The GoToNextFrameAsync takes in options which feels like the right place to specify things like that, but I have no idea what to pass in and can't find any documentation on the subject.

```
    public async static void AnimateImages(IEnumerable<StorageFile> files)
    {
        var outFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("test.gif", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var outStream = await outFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId, outStream);


        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
        {
            using (var str = await files.ElementAt(i).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(str);
                var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

                encoder.SetPixelData(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                    decoder.OrientedPixelWidth, decoder.OrientedPixelHeight,
                    decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY,
                    pixels.DetachPixelData());

                if(i < files.Count() -1 )
                    await encoder.GoToNextFrameAsync();
            }
        }

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        outStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having trouble with this too. It seems that whilst reading properties is OK setting any kind of property on a frame results in an exception. As far as I can tell from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63e0f635-7e5a-4eb7-87e7-76ae96d692f5) the BitmapEncoders are related to Windows Imaging Components, and as the page for [Native WIC Codecs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  states, there are no options for GIFs. It does seem odd though.